# PHP return new self two vaiables

Tags: php, class, oop, return

I working at large project and I have found this lines in code.

What is difference between them?

How it work without construct?

With two variables:

```
final public static function make(AbstracClass $variable, array $array = array())
        {
            $Class = get_called_class();

            return new $Class($variable, $array);
        }
```

With one variable in return new

```
final public static function make($array = array())
{
    return new self($array)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these methods have different signatures I can only assume they are members of different classes, so this is one reason for them calling construct with different arguments.

Also, because you say there is no constructor, I can assume these classes inherit from another class, because a class's constructor can be inherited.

Calling `return new self($array);` will always return an  instance of the class this statement is defined in.

Calling `get_called_class();` will always return the class you are calling from, even if this statement exists in an inherited class.

The way this function is used:

```
final public static function make(AbstracClass $variable, array $array = array())
{
    $Class = get_called_class();

    return new $Class($variable, $array);
}
```

Is the same as:

```
final public static function make(AbstracClass $variable, array $array = array())
{
    return new static($variable, $array);
}
```

Because `self` will always return the class the statement is defined in, and `static` will always be the class that is called.